# help with expression for nHibernate linq provider extension

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql, linq-expressions, nhlambdaextensions

I'm working on a custom linq extension for nHibernate by extending the BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod.  The technique is documented here:
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html

I've had success with implementing these for various types of operations, but I must say - converting a simple linq expression to its full expression tree is not easy! I'm stuck on one now.

For this example, I have three entities.  `Employee`, `Group`, and `EmployeeGroup`.  The EmployeeGroup class sets up a many-to-many relationship between Employee and Group.  I must specifically create the intermediate class because there are additional properties to track like specific permissions each employee has in each group.  So there are two one-to-many relationships, rather than an nHibernate many-to-many relationship.

Now say I want to get all groups that contain a specific employee.  I can write this query:

```
var groups = session.Query<Group>()
  .Where(g => g.EmployeeGroups.Any(eg => eg.Employee == employee));
```

This works fine, but it's a lot to type.  I'd much rather be able to do this:

```
var groups = session.Query<Group>().Where(g => g.HasEmployee(employee));
```

I start by creating an extension method like so:

```
public static bool HasEmployee(this Group group, Employee employee)
{
  return group.EmployeeGroups.Any(eg => eg.Employee == employee);
}
```

This works when querying a local list of groups, but not against the nHibernate session.  For that, I have to also create a linq extension and register it.  Just like in the article (linked above), I create a `GroupHasEmployeeGenerator` class that extends `BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod`.  I set its `.SupportedMethods` property to reference my HasEmployee extension method.

Where I get lost is in the override to `BuildHql`.  The expression to build gets complicated pretty fast.  I figure since I'm replacing the `.Any` clause - a good place to start is with the source for the built-in `AnyHqlGenerator` class.  But that doesn't take into account that the source is a property of the original element, and it also doesn't take into account that I don't have a lambda expression to represent the where clause. I need to build these parts manually.

There's no point in posting my attempts so far, as they've all be quite far from anything that would work.

**Will someone please help me convert this simple expression into the approprate set of methods for the `BuildHql` method override?**

If there is any better documentation out there for this, please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is a year old, but I ran into a very similar issue when implementing `BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod` today.

The input to `BuildHql` contains a collection of `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` arguments that are passed to your extension method.  Using these arguments, you can build an expression tree that represents the implementation of your extension method.  If the resulting expression is something NHibernate.Linq supports, then you can transform that expression to a subtree of Hql using the provided `IHqlExpressionVisitor`.

In your example:

```
public static bool HasEmployee(this Group group, Employee employee)
{
  return group.EmployeeGroups.Any(eg => eg.Employee == employee);
}
```

This would become something similar to this:

```
public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
{
    var AnyMethod = EnumerableHelper.GetMethod("Any", new[] {typeof(IEnumerable<EmployeeGroup>), typeof(Func<EmployeeGroup, bool>)}, new[] {typeof(EmployeeGroup)});
    var EmployeeGroupsProperty = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<Group>(g => g.EmployeeGroups);
    var EmployeeProperty = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<EmployeeGroup>(eg => eg.Employee);

    var EmployeeGroupParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EmployeeGroup));
    var EmployeeGroupPredicate = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(EmployeeGroupParameter, EmployeeProperty), arguments[1]), EmployeeGroupParameter);

    var CallExpression = Expression.Call(AnyMethod, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(arguments[0], EmployeeGroupsProperty), EmployeeGroupPredicate);

    return visitor.Visit(CallExpression);
}
```

I can't really test this specific example, but the same approach worked for me when providing support for my own extension method.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't done any nhibernate in awhile, so I'll have to go back and see it this would have solved the problem.  I'm marking this the accepted answer though, as it appears to be on the right track.  thanks!